# Which RDBMS is closest to the standard SQL

Tags: sql, rdbms

I'm looking for a free RDBMS that is closest to the standard SQL (maybe the latest SQL edition, 2011) and want to introduce it to my DB course students.
It is a good practice for newbie students to work and query on standard SQL, but popular RDBMSes like `MySQL` usually have lots of differences from the standard edition, which is confusing for them.

Which is the most popular RDBMS meeting this requirement? please provide reasons and references for your recommendation.

**P.S :** I'm not looking for such an RDBMS just for educational purposes. That's just an example. I mentioned this example because if I didn't, some people would ask : "Why do you want this ?!"

Comment: What exactly is "Standard SQL?"  Do you mean `SQL Server`?

Comment: @Siyual I think the OP means *exactly* what it says: **Closest to the *standard SQL*** (believe me, SQL Server is not an industry standard :P ) SQL is a language, not a product

Comment: How would you measure this? Implements the greater proportion of the standard? Fewest non standard features? Are all violations weighted equally?

Comment: You should choose Oracle , as it is closest to "standard SQL" , you may google it

Comment: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/

Comment: @Siyual : the *ISO/IEC 9075* standard. look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: @MartinSmith : I mean all of that you mentioned. I know it can not be measured in kilograms, but for example there might be some RDBMSes that their developers focused on making it as closest as possible to the standard. I'm looking for something like that.

Comment: postgres is much better at standards adherence than most (way better than mysql), and is free. see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/features.html

Comment: Each system has its advocates.  Each system deviates from the standard.  There are many parts to the SQL standard; it is unlikely that any system implements all parts exactly as required by the standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's why I asked it as "closest to the standard"

Comment: Which is a very, very subjective assessment...there is no objective way to measure the closeness that all will agree on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That makes me ask: "why is there a standard if there's no way to assess how close is X to the standard?" (sigh) sometimes life is so complicated :(

Comment: There was an SQL standard conformance suite back in the early to mid-90s, built by NIST, if I remember correctly.  The sponsors stopped maintaining it several years before the current millennium.  One trouble with testing SQL is that there are hundreds of options in the standard (as well as a dozen or so main parts to the standard).  Adapting the test suite to which options are supposed to be implemented is hard.  Then there are features that weren't standardized until after the major DBMS had implemented divergent variants on the same idea, plus all the features in each DBMS that are unique.

Comment: @ali Maybe the solution is... use any RDBMS you want and teach the most standard-compliant way to do things (that said, I have an open hostility to MS Access and SQL Server in that particular issue, so I would avoid them)

Comment: Since the question got closed I asked it on https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Which-RDBMS-is-closest-to-the-standard-SQL

Comment: also related  [Difference of implementations of the SQL standard in different relational database management system (RDBMS)](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/9348/1652)

Answer (score 4):

Before this question is closed: The only thing I can think of is [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). It claims in its [user manual](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html):

> HyperSQL 2 supports the dialect of SQL defined by SQL standards 92, 1999, 2003, 2008 and 2011. This means where a feature of the standard is supported, e.g. left outer join, the syntax is that specified by the standard text. Almost all syntactic features of SQL-92 up to Advanced Level are supported, as well as SQL:2011 core and many optional features of this standard. Work is in progress for a formal declaration of conformance.
>
> At the time of this release, HyperSQL supports the widest range of SQL standard features among all open source RDBMS.

Comment: I hope it will not be closed, I am not asking for opinions, I'm asking for references. good answer, I'm looking at this, while waiting for other answers.

Comment: From their site "HSQLDB (HyperSQL DataBase) is the leading SQL relational database software written in Java. (...)" I stopped reading here. A DBMS written in Java? I know that has been a increasingly lose of respect for software performance but this is ridiculous.

Comment: @ali Unfortunately, you know that *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam".* I'm trying to give the best answer I can, but that doesn't mean that this question is on-topic

Comment: @Havenard Just because you don't respect a particular platform it doesn't mean it can't be used to do good things. HSQLDB is quite a good RDBMS (I've used it)... and yes, it's written in Java (as many other programs), so what? Attention: I am not saying that HSQLDB *is* the best, I'm just saying that it's good enough

Comment: Its like using Access. Its slow and requires a lot more CPU and memory to accomplish the same task a C compilation would. I respect the choice of Java for an end user platform, but a DBMS is a server application that is supposed to be fast and efficient. Even .NET is faster than Java.

Comment: I wonder if this would be a good question for Software Recs?  It seems so based on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Havenard Well. the OP specifies that the recomendation is for students... sometimes speed and performance are not critical for eduational purposes... it all depends on what is really needed. That's the reason for this question to be off-topic (and I've voted to close it accordingly), but at least now the OP has a place to start with

Comment: @dsolimano I agree... you should flag it for moderator attention: Recommend this question to be migrated (I didn't know that SE had a site for software recommendations! Good to know!)

Comment: @Barranka done, hopefully the mods agree with us.

Comment: Java and performance should not be an issue for the toy databases students will make. I was in fact contemplating recommending sqlite for its accessibility, but it's just a little too permissive of sloppiness :-)

Comment: @Szocske Indeed! SQLite is quite... how to say it... has a "I give a damn" philosophy! (text stored in numeric fields, just to mention one, has been a really painful experience for me)

Comment: @ali One more thing. If you want to teach HSQLDB with a relatively friendly GUI, then take a look to OpenOffice or LibreOffice. Both suites' database apps are powered by HSQL

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not the strictest adherent to the standard, but I'd go with Postgres:

Clear and detailed documentation, they even go out of their way to highlight the deviations from the standard, which are few and far between.

Very simple to set up and run.

Usable CLI with readable error messages.

The core + extensions design is conductive to demonstrating advanced concepts like replication or sharding when they are due.

Gives your students an edge over mysql jockeys in their professional lives, and your institution an air of elegance without sacrificing practicality.